# In Drupal 8, paragraphs module, is there a way to search content based on what paragraph type it is?

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to discover if I have Paragraph Types that are not being used and clean things up a bit. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can create a dashboard view and will be filtered on paragraph types

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a try!